# Tags break custom Excerpt function

Tags: functions, tags, content

Quick question here. I have a function that echoes out the post-type's content (if none available, the excerpt). It looks like this:

```
function era_excerpt($post, $length = 11, $ext = ' ..') {
    if(is_int($post)) { $post = get_post($post); } elseif(!is_object($post)) { return false; }
    if(has_excerpt($post->ID)) { $the_excerpt = $post->post_excerpt; } else { $the_excerpt = $post->post_content; }
    $the_excerpt = strip_shortcodes(strip_tags(stripslashes($the_excerpt), '<a><em><strong>'));
    $the_excerpt = preg_split('/\b/', $the_excerpt, $length * 2+1);
    $excerpt_waste = array_pop($the_excerpt);
    $the_excerpt = implode($the_excerpt);
    $the_excerpt .= $ext;
    $post = $post->ID;

    return apply_filters('the_content', $the_excerpt);
}
```

I realized this function had a major issue: users starting a post-type with a special HTML tag, such as `<em>`, `<a>` and/or `<strong>`, broke the whole layout. Assuming this was caused by the "allowed tags" parameter of *strip_shortcodes*, I changed the function to:

```
function era_excerpt_new($post, $length = 11, $ext = ' ..') {
    if(is_int($post)) { $post = get_post($post); } elseif(!is_object($post)) { return false; }
    if(has_excerpt($post->ID)) { $the_excerpt = $post->post_excerpt; } else { $the_excerpt = $post->post_content; }
    $the_excerpt = strip_shortcodes(stripslashes($the_excerpt));
    $the_excerpt = preg_split('/\b/', $the_excerpt, $length * 2+1);
    $excerpt_waste = array_pop($the_excerpt);
    $the_excerpt = implode($the_excerpt);
    $the_excerpt .= $ext;
    $post = $post->ID;

    return apply_filters('the_content', $the_excerpt);
}
```

Sadly, this has not prevented users from breaking the layout whenever they start**º** a post-type's content with  (and probably other tags I am not aware of).

**º** I say *start* because, so far, adding tags in-between text has not broken anything.

**My question is**, how can I allow my users to use any tag they want when publishing a post-type, and echo the contents of it without breaking my site.

Thank you!

Comment: how does the layout break - are the starting tags unclosed in the html? have you tried to apply some code to close any open tags - such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810230/php-how-to-close-open-html-tag-in-a-string  ?

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for your reply - I already managed to fix it though. It wasn't a regular "break"; it actually replaced and wrapped all following tags of the website/theme with the tag used in the post-type. Thus my confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing the stripslashes() function.

Comment: Oh wow, awesome!